Ui and input not consistent w.r.t date invalid error
Expected behaviour
UI and input should be consistent
Actual behaviour

Datepicker version used
1.10.0
Example code
    $('.dt_picker').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        orientation: "auto",
        forceParse: false,
        format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
        startDate: '01/01/1970',
        endDate: '12/31/9999',
        todayHighlight: true,
        weekStart: 1,
        clearBtn: true,
        validateOnBlur: true
    })

